# Obtain part of a string using regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am dealing with strings that need to be converted into dates in Python. In a normal situation, my string would have `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S`. For instance:
`18/02/2013 09:21:14`

However in some occasion I could obtain something like `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S:%ms`, such as:`06/01/2014 09:52:14:78`

I would like to get rid of that `ms` bit but I need to figure out how. I have been able to create a regular expression which can test if the date matches:

```
    mydate = re.compile("^((((31\/(0?[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)\/(0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])))\/(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(29\/0?2\/(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})) (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d$")
    s = "06/01/2014 09:52:14:78"
    bool(mydate.match(s))

>>> False
```

However I do not know how to obtain only the interesting part, i.e `06/01/2014 09:52:14`
Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just `try` to `strptime` the string? If it fails, `rsplit` to remove the last part and `try` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*','','06/01/2014 09:52:14:78')
'06/01/2014 09:52:14'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QEmMbNLX1lRXg6sy)

Answer (score 1):

How about the `re.sub` function

```
>>> re.sub(r'( \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}).*$',r'\1','06/01/2014 09:52:14:78')
'06/01/2014 09:52:14'
>>> re.sub(r'( \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}).*$,r'\1','8/02/2013 09:21:14')
'8/02/2013 09:21:14'
```

- `( \d{2}(:\d{2}){2}) matches`hours:min:sec` saved in capture group 1
- `.*$` matches the milliseconds
- `r'\1'` replaced with contents of the first caputre group